# rails rspec error expected string got nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am new to testing in rails, I am trying to pass the test as below where it kept throwing back errors as

```
/scooties_coupon POST Coupon /scooties_coupons/:coupon_id with coupon coupon_id redeemed API_KEY returns redeemed id
     Failure/Error: expect(json['coupon']).to eq(scooties_coupon.coupon)

       expected: "6B2F5"
            got: nil

       (compared using ==)
```

Here is the code for the test I am running:

```
    context 'with coupon coupon_id redeemed API_KEY' do
      subject { post "/api/scooties_coupons/#{scooties_coupon.id}", headers: headers }

      it "returns redeemed id" do
        subject
        expect(json['coupon']).to eq(scooties_coupon.coupon)
        expect(json['redeemed']).to eq(scooties_coupon.redeemed)
      end
    end
```

my factory code:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :scooties_coupon do
    coupon { "43MDA" }
    redeemed { false }
    email { "email@host.com" }

    trait :redeemed do
      redeemed { true }
    end
  end
end
```

here's the model:

```
class ScootiesCoupon < ApplicationRecord

  has_paper_trail
  before_create :set_coupon_code
  after_update :send_activecamp_email_scootiescoupon

  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[^@\s]+@([^@.\s]+\.)+[^@.\s]+\z/ }

  def update_redeemed(redeemed = true, email = nil)
    email == self.email if email.present? || self.email.present?
    self.created_at + self.expires_in.seconds < DateTime.now if self.expires_in.present?

    self.update_attribute(:redeemed, redeemed)
  end

  private

  def set_coupon_code
    loop do
      self.coupon = gen_coupon
      break unless coupon_exists?
    end
  end

  def coupon_exists?
    self.class.exists?(coupon: coupon)
  end

  def gen_coupon
    return SecureRandom.hex[0..4].upcase
  end
end
```

I've tried to get rid of the validation on email but it doesn't seem to b e a major problem here, Could you give me a little idea of any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is controller's response?

Comment: hi @SergioTulentsev could you specify what that means? :) thanks!

Comment: Your controller, it accepts parameters and renders a response (the "json"), against which you make your assertions (which fail). What is the content of that response?

Comment: If you stick a `print json` right above `expect(json['coupon']).to eq(scooties_coupon.coupon)` and run your spec it should print something out (that's what Sergio is referring to). You might also want to add an assertion there `expect(response).to have_http_status(201)` (that's the status code for created, that your create worked)